# Extensions of a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Prove that there are infinitely many degree 5 extensions of $\mathbb{F}_{121}(x)$.

I know that $\mathbb{F}_{121}$ is isomorphic to the splitting field of $x^{121}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, but I'm not sure if this helps/how to proceed.

Comment: These aren't extensions of a finite field, as $\mathbb{F}_{121}(x)$ is certainly infinite. Extensions of finite fields of a given degree are unique.

Comment: The naive approach would be this: Find an infinite subset $S\subset \mathbb{F}_{121}(x)$ such that $\mathbb{F}_{121}(x)[\sqrt[5]{s}]$ and $\mathbb{F}_{121}(x)[\sqrt[5]{t}]$ are non-isomorphic extensions for distinct $s,t\in S$.

Comment: To add to @Slade's hint, the numbers $121$ and $5$ here are not very important, except insofar as $5$ does not divide $11$.